# How to call system.threading.timer on same thread?

Tags: c#

Everytime I switch something on my form, I restart my thread by doing (to call whatever was switched):

```
Retriever.Dispose();
Retriever = new System.Threading.Timer(CallPictureBoxRetriever, null, 0, 300000);
```

The problem is that this is yet creating another thread and closing the previous!

I am asking how can I call `CallPictureBoxRetriever(Object state)` on the same thread created so therefore I do not have to always dispose/recreate a thread; rather have 1 thread.

Comment: When you write "thread", do you really mean "timer"? While timers do necessarily make use of threads to do their work, they are not in and of themselves threads. I am having a hard time understand your question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way, and consider including [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly what the problem is, along with a precise explanation of what you want the code to do instead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you need to dispose of and re-create the timer?

Comment: The timer calls the function every 300000 miliseconds...aka a thread.

If something switches in my form, I need to re call the function WITHOUT WAITING for the aforementioned miliseconds to pass...aka delete and re create thread...

Comment: I think there may be some confusion between threads and timers here. It appears like you may be using the terms interchangeably when you really shouldn't be. They are not the same concepts. Can you clarify?

Comment: You're talking about forms, so it sounds like you are using WinForms: have you considered using a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): a far better timer in a GUI app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset the timer:

```
Retriever.Change(0, 300000); // reset to 300 seconds
```

First argument is *dueTime*:

> Specify zero (0) to restart the timer immediately.

Second is *period*:

> The time interval between invocations of the callback method specified
>   when the Timer was constructed, in milliseconds. Specify
>   Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling.

Full docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "does not work?" Is it throwing exception, not firing event, etc?

Comment: its c# number 1.

number 2 it isn't a timer, it is a System.Threading.Timer

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would create a thread that waits on an autoresetevent with a timeout of 30 seconds.  Then have your code set the autoresetevent when you want it to run immediately.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx